# How to handle redirects & http status codes at urls where a product becomes unavailable?

Tags: seo, redirects, 404, http-headers

I have this use case that happens frequently:

Lots of products for sale, periodically a percentage goes out of stock.

A user still browses in on the old url, to a location where a product used to be.

I want to redirect them to a search page, and notify them that the product is no longer available, and try to provide them with alternatives.

At the same time, I want to notify automated services (search engines, shopping engines) that that specific product is gone, in order to prevent continued hits to the urls in question.

What ways are there for gracefully handling this?

Edit: I'm refactoring/recoding the site in custom php code.  I also do have a dedicated 404 page, with links to places on the site, etc, but don't really want to duplicate the search page's functionality on the 404 page when a system is already in place in a different php script, and for most 404's I already have a more generic suggestion for alternatives.

Comment: For reference, I also found this: http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Webmasters/thread?tid=1bc5206b5e0fac47&hl=en#all link which talks about google's approach to 404 vs. 410, wherein they view 410 as a slightly more purposeful event, and a 404 as a slightly more random occurance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've put the 404 tag on the question whereas a page that returned a 410 ("Gone") error code would be better. For PHP you can do it like this:

```
header("HTTP/1.1 410 Gone");
```

before you start doing other output.

Your question is similar to this
[Is it better to have an ErrorDocument 404 redirect back to the homepage or a standard 404 error page?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/3131/is-it-better-to-have-an-errordocument-404-redirect-back-to-the-homepage-or-a-stan/3135#3135)
but the accepted answer for that suggests what sounds like one page, whereas your idea of a page which provides alternatives implies there are lots of them, one for each out of stock product.

Comment: +1. Just "410 Gone" response would be more appropriate than general "404 Not Found" for the product that was on site in the past but no longer there.

Comment: Yeah, part of my problem is the process.  I would think that if I return 404, I can't return a 301 redirect...

Comment: True, it's one or the other.

Comment: @Tchalvak No need for 301 redirect. Display your page (the content you want to show to the user) with 410 code on the same URL (URL for no-more-active/available-product) -- that will be the best for both user and search engine (user will see content/explanation while SE will take Response code).

Comment: Hmmm, so instead of a status code of 301 and a location redirection to the search, it would just have a status code of 410 and a redirection to the search, and that would work equivalently?

Comment: Err, and I did update the question, but I'm not sure that'd be evident, but I am working with a custom php system.

Comment: Sweet, just tested it and 410 gone and -then- a Location: redirect works fine, so that's what I'll have in play now, thanks.