# Switching canonical url when page returns 404

Tags: canonical-url, 404

I have some pages that have a short lifespan; this includes careers entries, landing pages and so on.

Currently when these are no longer available, they return a 404.

When these pages expire to a 404, would it be acceptable to switch the canonical url to an alternative location?

Comment: See also: [How to effectively close a page?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/50666/how-to-effectively-close-a-page) and  [Is it better to have an ErrorDocument 404 redirect back to the homepage or a standard 404 error page?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/3131/is-it-better-to-have-an-errordocument-404-redirect-back-to-the-homepage-or-a-sta)

Answer (score 1):

You should not use canonical tags on 404 pages.

If your page is gone, return a 404 or 410 error. If there is another page that is similar enough that it would fulfill the same user intent, then use a 301 redirect instead of a 404.

Answer (score 0):

It would be acceptable. However, from a user experience perspective, it would be much better to 301 redirect the user to the new canonical url, instead of displaying the 404 to the user and adding a rel=canonical for the search engine's benefit.

Comment: I don't think search engines honor canonical tags in 404 pages anyway.   A redirect is just an all around better option if you have a replacement.   However, redirecting to something that isn't a replacement (such as the home page) will just confuse users and not get any search engine benefit.

Comment: Agreed - you need to be redirecting to a page that is an alternative. But if it's not, you shouldn't be using it in your rel=canonical, either.